# Hashicorp Vault LDAP authentication issues

Tags: ldap, hashicorp-vault

We use LDAP as our access into Hashicorp Vault.

One of our users was deleted and recreated in AD... This use cannot log into the vault any longer, receiving a "**Authentication failed: internal error**" (rather than a "Authentication failed: ldap operation failed" that we see for a user that is not in AD or with an invalid password)

The only error we see is in the vault_audit.log (with passwords, and assessors munged, ip changed, and replaced with my name as example):

```
{
"time": "2022-09-12T19:03:55.457492415Z",
"type": "response",
"auth": {
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:xxxxxxx",
    "accessor": "hmac-sha256:yyyyyyy",
    "display_name": "ldap-ssiegler",
    "token_policies": [
        "default"
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "username": "ssiegler"
    },
    "entity_id": "aca5c682-b0c4-2f51-9681-b4244a23720b",
    "token_type": "service"
},
"request": {
    "id": "275b5b49-80ff-ee5f-a7f8-1e0c5a3dc645",
    "operation": "update",
    "namespace": {
        "id": "root"
    },
    "path": "auth/ldap/login/ssiegler",
    "data": {
        "password": "hmac-sha256:zzzzzzz"
    },
    "remote_address": "192.168.205.23"
},
"response": {},
"error": "internal error"
```

}

**"error": "internal error"**
being the only information...

I have removed the entities that referenced this user, with no change, and created a new entity that was able to have this ad user as an alias, so AD sees him...

Ideas?

Comment: Mmm, tough one. I imagine the user was create in the same structure, so that its distinguished name is the same? Something like `DC=com,DC=example,OU=user,CN=ssiegler`. Also : did the user log in at least once with this username/password elsewhere (to get rid of any "change password at next logon" hurdles)?

Comment: Yes, they have the same DN structure, and can log in, and perform other functions, as well as log into other consoles (such as, vCenter).

Comment: What is strange is that it looks like the authentication worked, you got a token back. Can you look up the entity id `aca5c682-b0c4-2f51-9681-b4244a23720b` in the UI and see what is wrong with it? Maybe delete it again?